# Can you override a Mac app's OS X version compatibility checking?

Tags: applications, macos, compatibility, hacking

I am wanting to use [this app](http://www.fixamacsoftware.com/software/spot4/index.php) in Mavericks, but the following message pops up when trying to run it, '...[App] is not compatible with Mac OS X 10.9.1':

[image]

I am thinking that the app will work just fine, and that the developer has just put a restriction to not allow anything above 10.7.x in some sort of compatibility settings inside its Package Contents - or however OS version checking within an App works on Mac OS.

Is there a way I can force it to run in Mavericks myself, via something like tweaking with numbers in a file in the .app Package Contents, changing some setting in System Preferences or doing a Terminal tweak of some kind?

Comment: This will be in the application code itself, and most likely cannot be circumvented. You have to wait for a new version.

Answer (score 1):

The above error is not the error provided by OS X. For comparison, this is the OS X error:

[image]

The error you have shown above will have been coded into the app specifically, and therefore not easily bypassed.

The best thing to do is contact the developer to see if they have a beta version of the app that you can test. Alternatively, wait for an update.

<sup>Also, code preventing the running of an app on a certain OS X version would usually have a good reason to exist, especially with utility software such as that. Bypassing it could have downsides…</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Often times I have seen people delve into the .APP's package contents. In some cases the version checking is done in one of the .plist files inside the app's package.

Someone with a little bit of technical knowledge, and a text editor, might be able to modify the correct plist file in the app's package.

Remember that apps downloaded from the Apple Store are signed cryptographically and changing things inside the package will cause the O/S to not run the app.